# Is it safe to short a capacitor with AC?

Tags: capacitor

Context: my house is equipped with an old ventilation system located in the attic, basically just an asynchronous motor with a fan that extract air.
It is possible to choose between two speed, full or low. For now this is controlled by a button in the kitchen, but I would like to remote control it.
The low speed is obtained by routing the current going to the motor windings through a capacitor that lower the (230 AC) voltage. Full speed just supply the windings with the line voltage.

I already have an home assistant server set up with a Zigbee controller, I also have a Zigbee switch capable of 10a (way enough for the fan).

Here's the wiring:

[image]

- INVERSEUR -> Speed toggle button
- GV -> Full speed
- PV -> low speed
- PH -> Live

The solution I'm thinking of is to put the Zigbee switch in the attic next to the ventilation and power it from the low speed input. When switched on it would bypass the speed toggle button and power the "full speed" line (bringing both the small speed and full speed at the same potential). The button in the kitchen would have to stay on low speed but that's ok.

Question: I'm wondering if it is safe to have the C2 capacitor connected to the line on both its leads (which is what would happen with this solution)?

The c2 capacitor:

[image]

Comment: FYI, it may be unsafe and illegal for you to do electrical installations on your house, depending on your jurisdiction. Unless you are a licensed electrician and know what you are doing. And who knows how your zigbee controller handles this, it may fry a solid state relay or weld mechanical relay contacts.

Comment: I assume [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IFya.png) is what you are envisaging?

Comment: @TomCarpenter yes exactly

Comment: Why don't you replace the button in the kitchen with a relay and use the zigbee to control the relay?

Comment: @Rodo the zigbee switch only have a NO pin, and it can toggle 230v AC, which is way too much to control classic relays (at least the one i have in stock). Also i have very little space in the button hole